# How can I simply place a button on the top right of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

My main goal is to create a btn that play/pause the song on my wedding site. 
I got it to work on the desktop view port, but not on the phone.

---

[image]
Notice the play btn on the far right, when clicking on it, it will play the song, the icon will toggle to pause, like this

[image]

So far so good, everything work perfectly fine.

---

Here come the issue, here what it look like on the 400px

[image]

I see it, but, they're not clickable at all.

I tried to inspect it, this is what I see.

[image]

I was thinking that I had the issue with z-index, I've tried to give one to my btn, but it still doesn't work.

I'm a little stuck now, please feel free to give me any suggestions.

---

## HTML

```
  <!--Header start -->
   <header>
    <!--menu start-->
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="navbar-wrapper" id="navbar">

        {{-- Music --}} -------------------------------------------------
        <div class="pull-right btn-music">
          <a class="pause_audio_btn hidden"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></a>
          <a class="play_audio_btn"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>
        </div>
        {{-- Music --}} -------------------------------------------------

        <div class="container">
          <!--Logo -->
          <div class="logo">
            <img id="logo" src="/img/love/logo_pink.png" alt="Roth-Long-Wedding">
          </div>
          <div class="logo_phone hidden">
            <img src="/img/love/logo_pink.png" alt="Roth-Long-Wedding">
          </div>
          <div class="navwrapper">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
              <div class="container">
                <div class="navArea">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navigation">
                      <li class="menuItem" id="home"><a href="#wrapper">Home</a></li>
                      <li class="menuItem"><a href="#when">Count Down</a></li>
                      <li class="menuItem"><a href="#theCouple">Couple</a></li>
                      <li class="menuItem"><a href="#eventsSchedule">Events</a></li>
                      <li class="menuItem"><a href="#photoAlbum">Gallery</a></li>
                      <li class="menuItem"><a href="#theBlog">Accommodation</a></li>
                      <li class="menuItem"><a href="#rsvp">RSVP</a></li>
                    </ul>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End Navbar -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--menu end-->

    <!--video header start-->
    <div class="banner  row" id="banner">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12 noPadd slides-container" style="height:100%">
        <!--background slide show start-->
        <div class="slide into_firefly">

          <!--header text1 start-->
          <div class="container hedaer-inner ">
            <div class=" bannerText clearfix ">
             <h1>Long & Roth</h1>
             <h4>WE ARE GETTING MARRIED</h4>

             <p class="ruler"><span></span>
               <a class="pause_audio_btn hidden"><i class="fa fa-pause"></i></a>
               <a class="play_audio_btn"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a>

               <span></span></p>

               <h4 class="date long">July 26th, 2016</h4>
               <h4 class="date short">-07.26.2016-</h4>
             </div>
             <p class="downArrow"><a href="#when"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></a></p>
           </div>
           <!--header text end-->
           <img src="/img/love/main/edit/retina.jpg" alt="Main Image">
        </div>    
        <!--background slide show end-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--banner end-->
  </header>
  <!--Header end -->
```

Comment: you have set the z-index of the logo to 9999. That is causing one issue.

Comment: Should I take it off ? I hope u can provide me a little more hints. :)

Comment: You should add the boostrap tag to your question, it has nothing to do with Jquery or javascript.

Comment: Please remove everything from your code that has nothing to do with the issue. Also, please post your css/javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a z-index issue, but z-index is tricky and only works when the elements have a position other than static (which is default).

```html
{{-- Music --}} -------------------------------------------------
<div class="pull-right btn-music" style="position:relative; z-index:99">
    ...
</div>
{{-- Music --}} -------------------------------------------------

<div class="container" style="position:relative; z-index:98">
    ...
</div>
```

(I put the styling inline for clarity)

There are likely other way to fix this, but this was the quickest.

Comment: Holy crab.. it works. You're saving my life mate. :)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the part where you have set the logo to `z-index: 9999`

Then add this to your css

```
.navbar-header button{
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: well lets see if it works first, but when I saw it was for your wedding I had to try and help

Comment: Unfortunately, It still unclickable. And this `.navbar-header button{
    float:right;
}` will make  the my nav-menu stay on the right side, overlapping with my play button. Please kindly advise - if I missed anything.

Comment: ok, I looked again on the google dev mobile view, which is only so good, but try this -- change the mobile.css first line to `@media only screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width:700px)` - this will change the max-width to 700px. This combined with removing the z-index should work. Let me know, if it doesnt work we can have a quick skype and i can show you in a couple of mins

Comment: Try it, still unclickable. :(

Comment: but did you also remove the `.navbar-header button{
    float:right;
}` meaning that the change is to remove the z-index, and increase the `max-width`?

Comment: What is your skype name pual ? U can delete it after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89611/discussion-between-paul-fitzgerald-and-ihue).

Answer (score 1):

Pull the button outside of .navbar-wrapper and put it as the first element under .menu

That'll work :)

Comment: Hi, I've followed what you suggested, and the play button won't display at all.

Comment: Did you make some changes between the time I suggested it and the time you implemented it? It worked when I did it on your site then, but I agree that it no longer does the trick. It did earlier.